# PM2 doesn't read sqlite database of discord bot written in node.js

Tags: node.js, linux, sqlite, pm2

When on my local machine and on linux vm, and I use node bot.js command to start my discord bot, the database in sqlite can be read perfectly. However, when I want to use PM2 on my vm to make my bot work in the background, it doesn't read the database and display the message after the m!shake command.

Here is my github: https://github.com/asukatae/miko-bot

What should I do?

Comment: "The message"? Can we get a little more than that?

Comment: sql.get(`SELECT * FROM omikuji WHERE no =${intStick}`).then(row => {
      msg.channel.send(`${row.message}`);
This part doesn't get read.